# androidmarketapi 0.6 login required

Tags: android, authentication, google-play

I'm using the android market api (androidmarketapi-0.6.jar) with success, but I am using my own gmail account to login using the MarketSession class:

```
MarketSession() session = new MarketSession();
session.login("user@gmail.com","pwd");
```

...and I'd like never use more my own gmail account, because I want to publish my app and I'd'd like that the final user can use it's own gmail account, but I do not want to prompt the user to write his username and password, so.... Is there any way to do this? I do not understand why is mandatory to login to query apps from the Google play, though anyone can see the Google Play with no login in the webb...has no sense...

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: I am still working on it, but currently i've signed up a test gmail account while i get a better solution...